# How to force cleanup/compaction in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I'm using Cassandra 2.1.8 for managing various assets, mostly images.
The cluster is setup with RF=3 on 3 nodes for the main CF, using Leveled Compaction.  I deleted a large portion of the data from the cluster (using a CQL script with lots of deletes), but the space has not yet been reclaimed.
Furthermore, one node experienced corruption on SSTables and I chose to wipe out its data and run repair to re-create it.
Now, the repaired node now uses 250GB in 100 SSTables, while the other 2 use 750GB in 300 SSTables.  "nodetool cfstats" shows 4.5M keys on one node, and 17M in the other two.

Is there a way to force a cleanup on these 2 nodes?  Running "nodetool compact" did not seem to have much effect on the 2 nodes - and it finishes rather quick.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why space is not reclaimed is because deletes in Cassandra are not "instant" - well at least from a storage perspective. It's not until `GC_GRACE` has expired and compaction runs that data effectively gets removed.

Now everyone's first instinct is to go and set `GC_GRACE=0` so that data goes away faster. That's not what you want to do. Here's why: https://lostechies.com/ryansvihla/2014/10/20/domain-modeling-around-deletes-or-using-cassandra-as-a-queue-even-when-you-know-better/

Your script that did a lot of deletes - did it do whole partition deletes? Or column deletes? Note, you may experience some overhead during compaction at that time depending on how many deletes you did and how you did your deletes.

Comment: gc_grace_seconds is 86400 (1 day) for this CF, and I had run the deletes about a week ago.  What puzzles me is that the repaired node was able to take only what's active, while the other two seem to keep holding the data longer.  Delete was run for entire partitions, not limited to columns.

Comment: Interesting, when you run nodetool cfstats on each of the nodes, what does it tell you 'maximum' and 'minimum' compacted partition size? I'm wondering if maybe you have large partitions that makes it seem like old data is there. Otherwise you may have left over snapshots which can be remedied by running 'nodetool clearsnapshot' https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/tools/toolsClearSnapShot.html

Comment: There are no snapshots.  Here's relevant info from cfstats, between 2 nodes (the one with data I expect to have and the one that seems to carry too much):

Comment: There are no snapshots.  If by min/max you meant space used vs total, they are the same in each node (2 nodes at ~700GB and one at ~150GB).  cfstats also shows the difference in keys estimated (currently 2.7M vs 16M).  It feels like some tombstones did not make it to 2 of my 3 nodes.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue with tombstones not beeing deleted. The solution was to set the unchecked_tombstone_compaction property on the table.

If I understand correctly this will allow the deletes even in cases were the table is not fully repaired

```
ALTER TABLE myTable WITH COMPACTION = { 'class': 'DateTieredCompactionStrategy','unchecked_tombstone_compaction': 'true' };
```